# Heroku web and clock idle seems idle in the same time

Tags: python, python-3.x, heroku, cron, clock

Hi I'd like to know is there any way to prevent the clock idle with the web in the 
same app

Here is my Procfilefile

`web: gunicorn badmintonApp:app 
clock: python cron.py`

and my cron.py is

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler
import subprocess
import os
import datetime
import requests
from crawler import googleExcelCrawler

sched = BlockingScheduler()


@sched.scheduled_job('interval', minutes=360)
def crawler_job():
    googleExcelCrawler.syncExcelToDB(os.environ.get('GoogleAuthKey'),"1sdEYj_w57iQaFhD5eNNOMLEhMbzlnhs7vR8Lz5RlChA")
    print('This job is insert data')
    print('This job is run every 360 minutes.')
@sched.scheduled_job('interval', minutes=3)
def timed_job():
    response = requests.get(os.environ.get('CURRENTDOMAIN'))
    print("Current Page Status " +str(response.status_code ))
sched.start()
```

I try to request my domain in every minutes , and  want to crawler the job after 6 hours, but seems not working....

> is there any way to prevent the clock idle with the web?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The only way to prevent that is to switch to hobby dynos.
On free dynos, when the web process goes to sleep, all other ones will do the same.